# Highcharts load pointStart from JSON. Milliseconds to UTC time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I made a graph with Highcharts which series is loaded from JSON.

I am bit new to handle JSON file though...

I want Highcharts to show date (in formart: YYYY/MM/DD ie.2013/04/01) on label of xAxis.

As far as I know, since I cannot write something like this in JSON,

```
"pointStart": [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 1)]
```

I wrote milliseconds instead.

My JSON:

```
[
    {
    "yAxis": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "name": "Y label",
    "data": [0,0,153,179,122,126,120,101,110,95,142,88,82,92,115,101,141,162,0,0,0,0,0,7,6,0,10,0,9,4,56,86,66,61,87,72,74,60,83,74,50,73,61,56,90,78],
    "pointStart": 1364774400000,
    "pointInterval": 86400000
},{
    "yAxis": 1,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Y label 2",
    "color": "#AA4643",
    "data": [4980,4572,5554,6147,5268,5221,5263,5084,4906,5000,5198,4777,4790,4549,4158,4294,4891,4689,4432,3925,3708,3723,3623,3831,3787,4353,4809,5046,4989,4815,4315,4556,4502,4725,4537,4540,4654,4367,4589,4874,4837,5032,5046,4633,4561,4576],
    "pointStart": 1364774400000,
    "pointInterval": 86400000
    }
]
```

And my javascript:

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%Y/%m/%d'
    },
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        align: 'right',
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d', this.x); //this returns invalid date.
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
},

...

$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
        options.series = data;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

This results `invalid date` on xAxis label.

But if I remove this part

```
formatter: function() {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d', this.x);
}
```

returns no error but results like `1. Apr` which I do not desire to show :(

Any solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with solution as follows:

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    day: '%Y/%m/%d'
},
labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    align: 'right',
    formatter: function() {
        var _date = new Date(this.value),
            _y = _date.getFullYear();
            _m = _date.getMonth() + 1,
            _d = _date.getDate(),
            _result = _y + '/' + (_m < 10 ? "0"+_m : _m) + '/' + (_d < 10 ? "0"+_d : _d);
        return _result;
    }
},
...
```

put milliseconds value to Date object in which I was able to handle value w/ such methods as `getFullYear()`, `getDate()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the date/time format wrong.  It's not `day: '%Y/%m/%d'`, it needs to be `day: '%Y/%y/%e'` see [dateTimeLabelFormats Highcharts API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats).

Comment: @Tomalak Oops I totally misread that, thought he was doing javascript and just json for the actual data, edited my answer to remove the quotes part.

Comment: actually I was able to display date with `'%Y/%m/%d'` format. I came up with a solution below.

Comment: @norixxx glad you got it figured out, but that seems like a lot of code/complexity compared to the Highcharts built-in dateTimeLabelFormats option

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter and Highcharts.dateFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat()

```
 labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d',this.value);
            }
```